# Unable to find httpd.conf

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

I'm running tomcat and I want to change the default `webroot` so that it points to another location.  Is there a way to find out what's running tomcat or where the default webroot is set as I can't find httpd.conf which is where I believe it's usually set?

Cheers,

Alexei Blue.

**UPDATE:**

It's been a long time since I looked at this question that I forgot about it.  In the end it turned out that we were using Apache HTTPD to accept requests from port 80.  From there we had the `webroot` and `ProxyPass` rules set in the `/etc/httpd/conf/virtual-hosts/default.conf` file (these can also be set in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`).  From there we had several tomcat instances running, all hosted on different ports which are setup in `apache-tomcat-x/conf/server.xml`.

When I wrote this question I was trying to setup a new tomcat instance to run an application in development and was told I would need to change the `webroot` to access my application, which was incorrect.  Instead what I needed was to include a `ProxyPass` rule so that when my application name was recognised in the URL, HTTPD would send the request to the correct tomcat instance to be processed.
E.g.

```
www.domain.com/myApplication

In /etc/httpd/conf/virtual-hosts/default.conf

ProxyPass /myApplication/ ajp://127.0.0.1:<ajp_port>/myApplication/
ProxyPassReverse /myApplication/ ajp://127.0.0.1:<ajp_port>/myApplication/
```

Where the ajp_port is setup in `apache-tomcat-x/conf/server.xml`.  I needed to ensure that non of the ports conflicted with other tomcat instances so remember to check all ports i.e. Shutdown, HTTP, HTTP with SSL, AJP etc.

Comment: `locate httpd.conf`? Although naming conventions differ on some OSs. The easiest way to go is to google `apache config file location <your OS name here>`

Comment: It's really odd, it should be httpd.conf, as I'm running Ubuntu, but locate finds nothing.  It's running on an amazone web service

Comment: tomcat doesn't need apache httpd to run, so you should first figure out if you're actually using/running httpd. If it's just tomcat, you need to look for tomcat config files.

Comment: I think that may be the case here.  I'll have a look round for tomcat config files, if you know of any that would really help.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat doesn't use httpd.conf, that is an apache file. The location of the individual webapps are kept in their individual web.xml files, but the location of all the configs are in ../tomcat6/conf/server.xml and web.xml

Is it where the files come from you want to move, or where it compiles and executes them from?

Comment: Well I'm trying to add a ColdFusion directory.  In the test environment where I work they run Apache and so the webroot just points to the ColdFusion root therefore calls in the JSP pages are something like: scr='xxx.cfm'.  However in my group we just set up Tomcat as Apache didn't seem releavent or needed.  Essentially what I need to do is either move the webroot to point to ColdFusion root or redirect and try the ColdFusion root.

Answer (score 2):

As @Woody says, Tomcat does not use httpd.conf files: that's an Apache httpd thing (httpd is a web server, Tomcat is a Java application server).

You didn't mention what OS you are using or what package management software you are using (e.g. yum, apt, etc.) so I'll give you generic information as if you had downloaded and installed Tomcat directly from apache.org (which I usually recommend people do for a number of reasons).

Tomcat keeps its server-wide configuration in the `conf/server.xml` file in the Tomcat base installation directory (often called $CATALINA_BASE for convenience): here, you configure things like what types of connectors (e.g. HTTP, HTTPS, AJP, etc.) to use and which ports they should listen to, clustering configuration, session persistence, global JNDI and realm resources. There are also `conf/web.xml` and `conf/context.xml` files that define defaults for all webapps deployed on that instance of Tomcat, but it's best to leave those files alone unless you have a really good reason to modify them.

When you want to deploy a webapp (under the default configuration), all you need to do is drop a .WAR file into the `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/` directory and the webapp will be deployed into a "context path" (aka URL prefix) that matches the name of the file minus the ".WAR" suffix. So, if you have a WAR file called mygreatwebapp.war, then it will be deployed such that your clients can reach it at `http://yourhost/mygreatwebapp/`. There is a special name you can give a WAR file so that it has an empty context path: if you name your WAR file `ROOT.war` (case matters), then your webapp can be reached at `http://yourhost/`. (If you would rather use exploded-WAR directories instead of WAR files, everything above still applies except the directories simply don't have the .war extension).

Given your original question, it sounds like all you want to do is drop a ROOT.war file into `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` (or replace the one that is already there): this will deploy whatever webapp you want into the URL space that you might call the "default webroot".

***Update***
If you want to change the directory where all the webapps live for a host, you can modify `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` and change the `<Host>`'s `appBase` attribute to point to, say, `/cfusion/main/www/`. That will deploy all the WAR files and directories in `/cfusion/main/www/` as separate webapps.

If you just want to serve a single webapp from an arbitrary location, you may create a deployment file under `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[EngineName]/[HostName]/[appname].xml`. This is a standard file like `META-INF/context.xml` and contains a `<Context>` element except that you will have to specify a `docBase` which points to your webapp (e.g. `/cfusion/main/www/mywebapp`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christopher but it's slightly different from that.  The default webroot needs to point a slightly deeper file structure i.e. "cfusion/main/www/".  This is because in the JSP they start from here.  I've been looking at creating a redirect when a 404 occurs to attempt this directory instead but I have no clue how to pass the URL through the web.xml file to the redirect file.

Comment: So, you have a directory all ready to go (`/path/to/cfusion/main/www/`) and you want to publish THAT on `http://myhost/`?

Comment: The main application is up and running.  The stuff in cfusion is a load of extras: reports, dynamic pages etc.  The jsp's in the main application use them all over the place but in our system they don't load as I haven't managed to sort how to set the defaultroot to "/cfusion/main/www/" instead of just the web apps folder.  So it looks like my option are: 1. Figure out how to set the defaultroot (as it is in the other system but that's using Apache) or 2. Use a regex to add the "/cfusion/main/www/" to all ColdFusion page references but these need to be removed and re-added every time we merge

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more information. It's still a bit unclear what you want to do. Are you trying to merge several directories such that they appear to be a single webapp? If so, then you'll have to merge them manually and deploy them as a single webapp. I don't believe ColdFusion (running inside a servlet container) can reference (i.e. import) pages from another webapp. If you are just trying to link from one webapp to the other, that shouldn't be a problem unless you want to share sessions, which you cannot do across webapps.